# Visual studio git UI doesnt shows new remote branches

Tags: git, visual-studio

Visual studio git UI doesnt shows new remote branches.  I have to delete the repo and clone the repo again to see the new branches.  Clicking refresh icon doesnt help.  IS there any way to refresh the view to show all the remote branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no UI element that brings all the remote branches consistently.  Invoke the git command prompt from "Actions" menu and run the following Git command

**`git fetch --all`**

Now you will see all the remote branches in the explorer.

Answer (score 0):

While not the best solution -- I have found that in Visual Studio 2022 - On the Git Changes panel, if you click the Sync button near the top right of the panel, it will pull down all the new server branches.